# Ionic Cordova Code Push Updates are always "pending"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, code-push

## Description

I put the code in place to do over the air updates, and it appears that the code does push, but every time I run:
`code-push deployment ls XXXXX`

I get:

Active: 0% (1 of XXX)
Total: 0 (XXX pending)

The "pending" never switches to success (but I do see the app update?)

## Reproduction

I am using an Ionic app (+Redux) have put in my app.component.ts:

`platform.ready().then(() => { this.ngRedux.dispatch(update()); });`
update() is in another file:

```
const changeUpdateStatus = status => ({
  type: 'UPDATE_STATUS',
  payload: status
});
export const update = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(changeUpdateStatus('INIT'));

  let sync = () => {
    let codePush = (<any>window).codePush;
    let SyncStatus = (<any>window).SyncStatus;

    if(!codePush){
      throw new Error('Code push not installed');
    };
    const keys = {
      'iOS': env.codePushKeys.ios,
      'Android': env.codePushKeys.android
    };
    const deploymentKey = keys[(<any>window).device.platform];
    console.log('Trying to sync code push using key: ', deploymentKey);

    codePush.sync(
      (status) => {
        console.log('status:', status);
        switch (status) {
          case SyncStatus.UPDATE_INSTALLED:
            dispatch(changeUpdateStatus('DONE'));
          break;
          case SyncStatus.CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE:
            dispatch(changeUpdateStatus('CHECKING'));
          break;
          case SyncStatus.DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE:
            dispatch(changeUpdateStatus('DOWNLOADING'));
          break;
          case SyncStatus.INSTALLING_UPDATE:
            dispatch(changeUpdateStatus('INSTALLING'));
          break;
          default: //ERROR, UP_TO_DATE
            dispatch(changeUpdateStatus('DONE'));
          break;
        }
      },
      {
        deploymentKey,
        installMode: (<any>window).InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
        mandatoryInstallMode: (<any>window).InstallMode.IMMEDIATE
      },
      (downloadProgress) => {
        // TODO: Add progress to state.
        if (downloadProgress) {
            console.log("Downloading " + downloadProgress.receivedBytes + " of " + downloadProgress.totalBytes);
        }
      }
    );
  }  
  sync() && onEvent("resume").then(sync).catch( (e) => {
    dispatch(changeUpdateStatus('DONE'));
    analytics.logError(e);
  });
};
```

Additional Information
cordova-plugin-code-push version: 1.11.0

List of installed plugins:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera-preview" spec="^0.9.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-upload" spec="^1.0.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sms-plugin" spec="^0.1.11" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-code-push" spec="~1.11.0" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.1.2">
        <variable name="FCM_VERSION" value="11.0.1" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^1.2.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="26.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="^1.0.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="^1.0.0" />
```

Cordova version: 7.1.0

iOS/Android/Windows version: All

Does this reproduce on a debug build or release build? Yes

Does this reproduce on a simulator, or only on a physical device? Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the air updates are now working.  The solution was to do a refactor and ensure that `sync` is literally the FIRST thing being called.  In this way, it can immediately "stamp" the build as successful when the new build starts-up.

I believe the problem was the fact that I had a bunch of code that executed prior to this (include a few API calls that may have taken a second or two).

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you fail to call `notifyApplicationReady()` on the Code Push SDK.  This method should be called somewhere near the startup of the app.  It effectively reports back to Code Push that the update was successful.  Without that the next time the app is started Code Push will likely trigger a rollback (depending on the details of how you deployed the update).

https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push

> notifyApplicationReady: Notifies the CodePush runtime that an installed update is considered successful. If you are manually checking for and installing updates (i.e. not using the sync method to handle it all for you), then this method MUST be called; otherwise CodePush will treat the update as failed and rollback to the previous version when the app next restarts.

Comment: Thanks for replying with the docs.  I shouldn't need to call notifyApplicationReady() - "If you are using the sync function, and doing your update check on app start, then you don't need to manually call notifyApplicationReady since sync will call it for you. This behavior exists due to the assumption that the point at which sync is called in your app represents a good approximation of a successful startup."